# Data Extract for bounces in recurring program

Tags: data-export

Is it possible to build a data extract that would pull bounces for a set of welcome e-mails (which run daily as part of a program) and place the file on our ExactTarget FTP?

I know with Tracking Extracts I'm able to pull that data, however that's only available with a Send ID. Since these e-mails are part of a program that runs daily, the Send ID changes daily, making any sort automated of extract seemingly impossible.

Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I could imagine doing this:

1. A data extension that holds all the Bounce fields you are interested in
2. A query that selects these fields from the Bounce data view, with a subquery on the Job data view to get your job ID based on EmailName, EmailSubject, etc; use this to overwrite (or update, depending on what you want) your data extension
3. A data extract of type 'Data Extension Extract' to get that data extension
4. A file transfer to move that file to your FTP
5. An Automation Studio automation that runs steps 2-4 every day

Documentation on queries and data views: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/